# How to continuously update a QLabel with QImage in Qt when a window is open?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qlabel, qimage

I have a scenario where I need to continuously display frames from a `QImage` in a `QLabel` when a window is open in a Qt application.

I have 2 classes involved in this scenario:

1. `Camera` (where the buffer is generated from a device).
2. `Scenarios` (the place where I need to display images from the Camera). Scenarios is not the main window of Qt. It's a form that opens after clicking on button in main window: `scenarios_->show();`

In my `main` function, I have written the following code:

```cpp
...
Scenarios scenarios;
Camera camera(0, argv);
camera.start();
QObject::connect(&camera, SIGNAL(foo(unsigned char *)), &scenarios, SLOT(bar(unsigned char *)));
...
```

The `Camera` class emits the signal `foo(unsigned char *)`, which includes:

```cpp
std::map<unsigned long, unsigned char *> ThermalImages;
unsigned long serial = itDevices->first;
...
getting image
...
emit foo(ThermalImages[serial]);
```

This part works fine. In the `Scenarios` class, in the `bar` slot, I receive the buffer and can create a `QImage` from it:

```cpp
QImage thermalImage_;

void Scenarios::bar(unsigned char *thermalImage) {
    thermalImage_ = QImage(thermalImage, 384, 288, QImage::Format_RGB888);
}
```

Now, here's the problem. I want to display this `QImage` in a specific `QLabel` in the `Scenarios` widget. To check that the buffer is not empty and that the `QImage` is correctly created, I added a button to the form that displays the image:

```cpp
void Scenarios::on_button_update_clicked() {
    ui_->label_thermal->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(thermalImage_));
}
```

If I click the button, I get the current frame displayed. However, my goal is to continuously update the `QLabel` without having to click the button. I want the video stream to be displayed continuously when the form is open. I need a way to refresh the information in the `QLabel` automatically every time a new frame is available.

I tried using `connect` in the constructor of the `Scenarios` class, but it seems to trigger only once.

How can I resolve this issue so that when the window is open, I immediately see a continuous stream of images in the `QLabel` without having to click a button?

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: This might help: [How to slow down printing progress values on a label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76403278/how-to-slow-down-printing-progress-values-on-a-label/76407188#76407188)

Comment: [How can I put in a loop the change of a label in QT(c++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67772929/how-can-i-put-in-a-loop-the-change-of-a-label-in-qtc) **|** [How to properly using infinite loop in Qt GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68508647/how-to-properly-using-infinite-loop-in-qt-gui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Qtimer (https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtimer.html) , init in constructor and connect timer to slot to update slot at regular intervals.

or you can refer to this for more efficient update , [Efficient way of displaying a continuous stream of QImages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22353080/efficient-way-of-displaying-a-continuous-stream-of-qimages)